Finding polynomials $g_1,\ldots,g_{n+1} \in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]=R$ s.t. $k[f_1,\ldots,f_{n+2}]\subseteq k[g_1,\ldots,g_{n+1}] \subsetneq R$
We try to generalize this nice question.
Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero and let $R=k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, $n \geq 1$.
Assume that $f_1,\ldots,f_n,f_{n+1},f_{n+2} \in R$ are such that:

Each $f_j \notin k[f_1,\ldots,f_{j-1},f_{j+1},\ldots,f_{n+2}]$.
$k[f_1,\ldots,f_{n+2}] \subsetneq R$.


Question:
Is it true that there exist polynomials $g_1,\ldots,g_{n+1} \in R$ such that $k[f_1,\ldots,f_{n+2}] \subseteq k[g_1,\ldots,g_{n+1}] \subsetneq R$?

I do not mind to further assume that $k=\mathbb{C}$.
Perhaps one can adjust the proof of the quoted question to our case.
A Remark:
For $n=2$, we ask if it is possible to find $g_1,g_2,g_3$ such that $[f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4] \subseteq k[g_1,g_2,g_3] \subsetneq k[x,y]$. Notice that the answer is negative for fewer $f_i$'s and $g_j$'s, for example: There are no $g_1,g_2$ such that $k[x^2,x^3,y] \subseteq k[g_1,g_2] \subsetneq k[x,y]$.
Thank you very much.

Edit: It would be nice first to answer the following question --

Question: Is it possible to replace $\mathbb{C}$ by an arbitrary field $k$ of characteristic zero, even just in the original question? I am not sure where the assumption that the base field is $\mathbb{C}$ is applied.

